# .NET System.Timer Question - Event triggered when Timer.Start() is called?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

When a timer's autostart is set to true, does it execute the elapsed event automatically, or just wait for the elapsed interval then executes the event?

Comment: Nitpick - `System.Timers.Timer` doesn't have an `Autostart` property.  It **does** have an `AutoReset` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean the [Timer.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.start.aspx) method in the `System.Timers.Timer` class, and the answer is no, `Elapsed` doesn't get fired until the first interval actually elapses.

Note: If by `Autostart` you actually mean `AutoReset`, then that property automatically *stops* the timer after the first `Elapsed` event is fired.  It has no direct effect on what the `Start` method does.

Comment: Thanks for this Aaronnaught. Yes, I do mean AutoReset. Thanks for the ansywer! :D